# Fig tree wilting and the fruit also does not look healthy

Tags: figs, wilting

Leaves from one of the main twig of my fig tree (6-8 years old) is wilting. Could someone please guide me what/why it's happening and how to fix.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Has the weather there been unusual recently? Too hot or cold? Too wet or dry? Any other plants nearby affected? Any sign of insects or fungus?

Comment: Figs need good water supply for fruit.

Comment: @BobaFit yes, weather has changed too hot recently. Not sure how to check about fungus. About insects, while digging earth near its trunk I found some tiny insects not sure what it was

Comment: About insects, some of them were of white color, others were black looks like ground beetle larva. I dig it again today but did't find any insects